# Error in `/usr/bin/python3': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00403eb0

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have created a service which starts python script on system boot. The script must run forever. Script receives some data on UDP and reverts after processing it. It performs some i2c, spi and GPIO related tasks in it. Its working without any error.

One html page always remains open in my raspberry pi forever.

The python script automatically stop after approx 8 to 10 hours. When I explored, I found that it is following error.

```
Error in `/usr/bin/python3': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00403eb0 
Dec 24 19:53:03 raspberrypi systemd[1]: platform_slave.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=6/ABRT
Dec 24 19:53:03 raspberrypi systemd[1]: platform_slave.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 24 19:53:03 raspberrypi systemd[1]: platform_slave.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
```

I already explored following link but nothing found worthy.
[*** Error in `python3': free(): invalid pointer: 0xb70c3578 *** Aborted (core dumped)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51015309/error-in-python3-free-invalid-pointer-0xb70c3578-aborted-core-du)

Does anyone having idea about above errors?

Comment: The python3 interpreter/  runtime is crashing because of an error in the underlying C code. It's likely that this is some extension (native library) that is at fault. But you've told us very little about the code, so this is impossible to diagnose. What does your Python code do? What libraries does it use?

Comment: In my code I am importing socket, json, time, threding and RPi.GPIO. Python version is 3.5.3.

Comment: Given that the others are part of the standard library, I suspect the RPi.GPIO library has a bug. You should report this to the upstream project.

Comment: May be there is a bug in RPi.GPIO. I solved this error by rewriting more compact and structured code.

Comment: I am dealing with a similar crash, in my case it happens after several hours of sending data over SPI (spidev library).

Comment: Have you checked with available memory? It may be running out of space.

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed a bug in Raspian (or spidev up to 3.5, or the SPI Linux driver itself).
The interface will cause the program to crash after 2^32 bytes sent. "try... except..." does not help.

Please see this discussion for more details.

[Why does my long-running python script crash with "invalid pointer" after running for about 3 days?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55569234/why-does-my-long-running-python-script-crash-with-invalid-pointer-after-runnin/64006201#64006201)